# Parallelising Java 8 Stream.filter()?

Tags: java, performance, java-8, java-stream

I'm making a music conversion program to automate a lot of trivial conversions and convert large libraries of music to various form of .opus files. (Things like bitrate modification for mobile devices, and automatic generation of metadata).

I have an issue with a particular stream (Containing all the `Path`s of the music files (This is a very large stream as music libraries tend to be large) where I currently go through a 2 step process to perform operations on all the library file `Path` objects.

First they are filtered (To ensure that they don't already exist in the `Converted` folder, (if they do they are skipped and not run through the converter) then the ones that aren't present in the converted folder are converted into a conversion task (`Runnable/Callable`) and submitted to an executor pool.

I'm running into a performance bottleneck at the filtration part. I've run the typical profiling/performance optimizations that I could from a code perspective, but the type of comparisons that I have to do fundamentally take a long time to do (They're disk operrations, calling an external library called `exiftool`, to get and compare file metadata). These take a while, but they're all being run by the `Main` thread on the Netbeans profiler.

TL;DR Psuedo-Code:

```
Stream<Path> stream = ...
stream.filter(path -> exiftoolFilter(path)).forEach(path -> convert(path));
```

How can I optimise the filtration performance by using more than the `Main` thread for the handoff to `forEach`? I was thinking about using spliterator, but I've never used it and have only the vaguest notation of how it works from tutorials such as (http://www.baeldung.com/java-spliterator). I would prefer to stay within the Java8.Streams API.

Can you show an example (Even in pseudo-code) of an implementation?

I'm using Java 8_171 on Kubuntu 18.04 if that helps. (Netbeans is a few integer version behind on Java releases and is in the process of building newer versions of the program after donating the code to Apache)

**Edit 0:**
I've made a consideration with regards to performance.
The main performance bottleneck that I could identify is a single filter statement from the file path walk stream.

It is essentially this:

```
fileWalk(rootMusicDir).filter(path -> 
!(existInFolder(path) || filterByFileAttributes(path) || 
filterByFileName(path)))
```

Where: `existInFolder(Path)` is a short function that simply checks if the filename exists in the "already indexed" folder, `filterByFileAttributes(path)` is a very long to run function that uses `exiftool` and views a file's metadata to get its attribute: `Title` and see if Title.opus exists in the directory, and the filterByFileName(path) looks for patterns in the file name itself to see if it can break it up and see if that exists in the directory.

We see that the above **overall** boolean statement is only false if one or more of the internal function calls are `true`. Which makes sense since we don't want to index anything that already exists in the folder, and it is only true if none of the internal function calls are true. (Note: I don't know if this is the ideal configuration of boolean operations, it's just one I made up that produces the appropriate functionality)

For .opus files this is done for a few reasons. 
1) The main objective of this program is to save as much metadata as possible, so just copying it/not caring isn't an option.
2)Music Files can exist in at least 2 different forms, as : `SomeArtist -- SomeTrackTitle`, or, when it is finished it should just appear as `SomeTrackTitle.opus` on the disk, with its internal file attribute set to `Artist = SomeArtist` & `Title=SomeTrackTitle`. This function also runs to make a low bitrate duplicate of the entire library for mobile devices.

For reference, I said that this program was a converter. It takes some filepath and converts it to an .opus file. But the two filenames can be different. So we might be converting from `Artist -- Title` -> `Title` It can also be `Title.opus` (With attributes set) -> Title.opus (With Attributes Set, but lower bitrate) In this narrow case, this subroutine is an upgrade function to upgrade older versions of the library to the new naming format (Mentioned below). So it might have these different names, whereas all outputs are just `Title`

From what I recall about Java optimization and boolean logic statements, the JVM will attempt to short circuit any boolean logic statement if it can. I reordered the previous `predicate` to its current configuration based on the statistical probability of encountering the situation where each function would run. Before, it used to be that the longest time to run function would be called first, but this is no longer the case. This cut the running time from 10:00 -> 00:59 using 889 files. So not bad, but not good either for only comparing filenames.

The main issue appears to be that earlier versions of the program didn't have a consistent naming scheme, or rather that what I thought the name would be changed (Older version of the program were ok with either above format of name). I didn't anticipate using or setting .opus metadata because it appeared to be impossible. Then I realised that ffmpeg supported .opus and found opusenc (Kubuntu's opus encoder) and exiftool (For reading metadata). Since I've standardized on a file format for the name now, it should go much faster in the future.

Comment: Replace `.stream()` with `.parallelStream()` when you create it?

Comment: Also: if you're doing a lot of IO (files, or network) then it's unlikely multiple threads will help.  These sort of things are often IO bound, and depend on the speed of the IO, not the speed of the CPU.  Going faster with more threads won't help if the IO is still slow.

Comment: @thatotherguy I tried using `parallelStream` and saved 40 seconds on the conversion. That wasn't a bad idea actually. I had just never used `parallelStream` due to not having experience with it. It's not a terrific speedup (10 minutes for total conversions on 8 cores), btu it's better than no improvement. I think markspacce was right and the program appears to be mostly I/O locked. Looks like it's as fast as it can get from a non-structural enhancement perspective.

Comment: @markspace IO-bound task can profit from parallelization, too, as the disk can be sent multiple requests, which then can be served faster (with HDD, disk seeks can be optimized; no idea about SSD). Once I did some recursive directory read and could get a speed up of factor 3 with 4 threads (but it didn't scale any further).

Comment: I guess, the biggest improvement could be in your usage of the `exiftoolFilter`. Are you sure, nothing gets done repeatedly and/or needlessly? Can't you extract all the information once in something not so terribly slow? Can you show us the code?

Comment: @maaartinus I had that suspicion, but lacked the actual experience to make any statements. Honestly, I have no idea about SSDs and performance, but probably? And yes, there are no repeats, I've verified this by stepping through it in the debugger. I think it's a formatting issue where, for some files, there is no way to determine the filename aside for actually looking at the attribute metadata.